# Oracle: create stored procedure to insert results from another stored procedure into a table

Tags: oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2017, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle stored procedure `spFinTest` that I use in an SSRS report.

I wish to create another stored procedure `spFinTestInsert` that takes the output of `spFinTest` and inserts it into a table `sbceybudget_financial_year`.

I can create an all in one stored procedure that inserts the data into the destination table, but what I am looking to achieve is to just have the one stored procedure that can have code updates for data extracts and not to have to update a second separate insert stored procedure that has the same code.

So, update in one place only and reuse the same stored procedure.

The following is a simplified version of the main stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure spFINTEST
    (s1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN

OPEN s1 FOR

SELECT
  FIN_YR + 1 AS FIN_YR,
  SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS
FROM
  sbceybudget_financial_year
WHERE
  fin_yr = 2021
;
END spFINTEST;
```

This stored procedure only has an "out" variable.

The final intention is once I can do this, then I will call `spFinTestInsert` from an "Execute SQL Task" in an SSIS package.

I'm a bit stumped as to how I create this second stored procedure that calls the first and inserts the results into a named table, so if anyone can help I would be most grateful.

Comment: Corrected.  Sorry for my heinous crime.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in a package: it allows you to declare cursor type easily to make it more clear.

Test table:

```
create table sbceybudget_financial_year(
  fin_yr            int,
  SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS int
)
/
```

Package specification:

```
create or replace package pkg_spFIN as

   type spFIN_RowType is record(
      FIN_YR            sbceybudget_financial_year.FIN_YR%type,
      SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS sbceybudget_financial_year.SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS%type
   );
   
   type spFIN_CurType IS REF CURSOR RETURN spFIN_RowType;
   type spFIN_tab is table of spFIN_RowType;

   procedure spFINTEST (s1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
   procedure spFinTestInsert;
end pkg_spFIN;
/
```

Package body:

```
create or replace package body pkg_spFIN as

   function get_cursor(n int) return spFIN_CurType is
     c spFIN_CurType;
   begin
     open c for
      SELECT
        t.FIN_YR + 1 AS FIN_YR,
        t.SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS
      FROM
        sbceybudget_financial_year t
      WHERE
        t.fin_yr = n;
     return c;
   end;
   
   procedure spFINTEST (s1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   is
   begin
     s1:=get_cursor(2021);
   end spFINTEST;

   procedure spFinTestInsert
   is
     cur spFIN_CurType;
     tab spFIN_tab;
   begin
     pkg_spFIN.spFINTEST(cur);
     loop
       fetch cur bulk collect into tab limit 100;
       exit when tab.count()=0;
       for i in 1..tab.count loop
         dbms_output.put_line(tab(i).FIN_YR);
         dbms_output.put_line(tab(i).SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS);
         -- or insert:
         -- insert into sbceybudget_financial_year(fin_yr, SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS)
         --  values(tab(i).FIN_YR, SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS)
         -- you can change it to FORALL insert
       end loop;
     end loop;
   end spFinTestInsert;
end pkg_spFIN;
/
```

Test data:

```
begin
insert into sbceybudget_financial_year(fin_yr, SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS) values(2019,19);
insert into sbceybudget_financial_year(fin_yr, SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS) values(2020,20);
insert into sbceybudget_financial_year(fin_yr, SCHOOL_YEAR_WEEKS) values(2021,21);
commit;
end;
/
```

And finally test call:

```
call pkg_spFIN.spFinTestInsert();
```

Full example on DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c31a5714e5db74eaa3a83fae03964349

Comment: Hi Sayan, apologies for not coming back sooner.  I will be trying your solution when I have a bit more time.  Littlefoot's solution has worked for me, but I am keen to try yours.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your tables so I'll use Scott's `DEPT` for illustration.

This is the "target" table; values fetched by ref cursor will be inserted into it:

```
SQL> create table test_dept as select deptno, dname from dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.
```

This is data I expect:

```
SQL> select deptno, dname from dept where deptno <= 20;

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
```

This is your current procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure spfintest (s1 out sys_refcursor)
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    open s1 for select deptno, dname from dept where deptno <= 20;
  5  end spfintest;
  6  /

Procedure created.
```

This is a procedure which calls `spfintest` and inserts values into `test_dept`:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure spfitestinsert as
  2    rc sys_refcursor;
  3    --
  4    l_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  5    l_dname  dept.dname%type;
  6  begin
  7    spfintest(rc);
  8    loop
  9      fetch rc into l_deptno, l_dname;
 10      exit when rc%notfound;
 11
 12      insert into test_dept (deptno, dname)
 13        values (l_deptno, l_dname);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec spfitestinsert;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test_dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH

SQL>
```

Everything is here, so I guess it works.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, apologies for not coming back sooner.  Your solution has worked perfectly for me.  I will be trying Sayan's when I have a bit more time.  Many thanks!